# Java MimeBodyPart wrongfully showing as attachments

Tags: java, outlook, mime-message, mimebodypart

I am having a really weird problem when adding more than one `MimeBodyPart` to a `MimeMultiPart`. Essentially, if the `MimeMultiPart` is mixed, then all `MimeBodyPart` objects are added as attachments, except for the last one, which is added to the body. If the `MimeMultiPart` is alternative, then only the last `MimeBodyPart` is added to the body.

I am just trying to write a simple email which should have an opening (text), followed by a table (html), and finally a closing (text).

## Code

Here is the code for my function creating the email. It generates the `MimeMessage` and then opens it in Outlook as a draft.

```java
public void writeEmail() throws Exception {
        //Create message envelope.
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage((Session) null);
        
        //Set destination and cc
        msg.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse("SELECT@ACCOUNT"));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("support@bar.com"));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("manager@baz.com"));
        
        //Create and set the subject
        String subject = "subject"; 
        
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        
        //Make the message as a draft
        msg.setHeader("X-Unsent", "1");

        
        //Create the body
        MimeMultipart mmp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        
        //Tests
        String opening = "Opening";
        String html = "<h1>" + table + "</h1>";
        String closing = "Closing";
        
        MimeBodyPart openingPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        openingPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        openingPart.setText(opening, "utf-8");
        
        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        htmlPart.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        
        MimeBodyPart closingPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        closingPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        closingPart.setText(closing, "utf-8");
        
        mmp.addBodyPart(openingPart);
        mmp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        mmp.addBodyPart(closingPart);
        
        msg.setContent(mmp);
        msg.saveChanges();

        //Save as a temporary file
        File resultEmail = File.createTempFile("email", ".eml");
        
        try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(resultEmail)) {
            msg.writeTo(fs);
            fs.flush();
            fs.getFD().sync();
        }

        System.out.println(resultEmail.getCanonicalPath());

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.command("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "outlook.exe", "/eml", resultEmail.getCanonicalPath());
        Process p = pb.start();
        
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } finally {
            p.getErrorStream().close();
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();
            p.destroy();
        }
}
```

## Question

How can I render all the `MimeBodyPart` as text inside of the email body, instead of them being wrongfully added as attachments?